# break a long list into multiple columns in restructured text

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is there a way to break a long list into multiple columns in restructured text?

source:

```
* a
* b
* c
* d
* e
* a
* c
* a
* d
* e
* f
```

result:

```
* a   * e   * d
* b   * a   * e
* c   * c   * f
* d   * a
```

The goal is to provide the source list in a reST directive
rather than using some other language to read the source list and then write the result text with the ".. raw::" directive in reST.  Such as this hypothetical `list-multicol` directive:

```
.. list-multicol::
   :columns: 3

   * a
   * b
   * c
   * d
   * e
   * a
   * c
   * a
   * d
   * e
   * f
```

Extra credit for option to balance columns (same number of items +/- 1) no wider than the page or a specified number of columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, the `hlist` directive does this.

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-hlist

Here's the example:

```
.. hlist::
   :columns: 3

   * A list of
   * short items
   * that should be
   * displayed
   * horizontally
```